# Unnecessary re-render of a component when wanting to add an animation with MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this component that needs to expand/shrink depending if left drawer is open or closed

[image]

**This is the code**

```
const MainContent = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })<{
    open?: boolean;
}>(({ theme, open }) => ({
    background: '#fafafa',
    height: 'calc(100vh - 64px)',
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: '38px 53px 0px 53px',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: `-260px`,
    ...(open && {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: 0,
    }),
}));

const Home = () => {
    const isDrawerOpen = useSelector(value);
    const isAppSelected = useSelector(value);

    return (
        <Box style={{ display: 'flex', overflowX: 'hidden' }}>

            {/* Main content */}
            <MainContent open={isDrawerOpen}>
                    <>
                        <SinAsignarHero />

                        {/* Handeling server errors */}
                        <RecogidasIssue />
                    </>
                )}
            </MainContent>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

and, as you can see, `MainContent` which is a custom component (from MUI) will open/shrink depending on this value that comes from my store (i'm using redux), and it does what it is supposed to do, but, everytime i do that, the other components that live inside `MainContent` will re-initialize useState, variables and everything, like it somehow is re-rendering the components when `isDrawerOpen` values changes, i don't want that behavior.

Is it probably that, because of that value, that is changing depending on the user clicking to see/close the left drawer, it will manage to re-render the component ? How can i avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here, is that, since the value `isDrawerOpen` is changing constantly, your component is changing as well even though there aren't things changing there directly.

I would suggest you to read this article about how to use `React.memo` it will help you to avoid unnecessary re-renders when react components are the same.

[Here it is !](https://linguinecode.com/post/prevent-re-renders-react-functional-components-react-memo)